# DOM returns empty object

Tags: php, dom, object

This is my code:

```
<?php
$content = utf8_encode( file_get_contents( "data.xml") );
$XML = new DOMDocument();
$XML->loadXML($content);

echo "<pre>" . print_r($XML, 1) . "</pre>";
?>
```

It does return:

```
 DOMDocument Object
(
)
```

I've read its a bug or something, since both `var_dump` and `print_r` or any will return an empty object element.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domelement.php#86224

This guy gave an solution to better use:

```
$xml = $XML->saveXML($XML);
echo "<pre>" . print_r($xml, 1) . "</pre>";
```

But then, when I'm reloading the page, it looks like there are only spaces, because I can't see anything, but I can select it...

Where is the problem, have you guys any solutions for that?

Comment: Is `data.xml` a valid XML file?

Comment: what happens if you just `die($content)`?

Comment: [`saveXML()`](http://php.net/domdocument.savexml.php) returns a string you shouldn't need `print_r`.

Comment: Do not expect `var_dump` or `print_r` to work on DOM objects, they will not show you their content. Also, just look at the _source_ of the page, do not rely on stuff like `<pre>`'s...

Comment: nachito: yes, its a valid file.
Ben D: nothing, just blank page.

Comment: +1 for pointing me in the right direction, on the inability of var_dump to show dom.

Answer (score 0):

I've experienced the same problem. It seems that the HTML validation code is very sensitive to errors. If you turn on warnings, you'll probably see a bunch of warnings when the HTML content is loaded (at least that was the case for me -loading up a remote page).

I've found that it particularly gets hung up on HTML entities. It also seems to get caught up on HTML tags compiled in javascript.

I attempted to hack through it by replacing `&`'s with `&amp;`'s just to see if I'd be able to get a properly parsed object back. I continued to get errors on JS though.

Basically, make sure you have debugging output visible and check for warnings. The content might end up being the issue here.

Edit:
I did a little searching and have found this library which seems to opperate very similarly to DOMDocument, but doesn't appear to explode on small issues in the HTML:
http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/

I was able to load up the web page I was having problems with -without error. Might be worth a shot in your future projects.

Answer (score 0):

What the author forgot to add was `htmlspecialchars()`:

```
$xml = $XML->saveXML($XML);
echo "<pre>", htmlspecialchars($xml, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'), "</pre>";
```

Without it, the XML output doesn't get escaped and you won't see the tags.

Answer (score -1):

A `var_dump` on `DOMDocument` always returns an empty object.

Illustration:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file('test.xml'); //load your xml

var_dump($xml); //var_dump via SimpleXML (lot of data)

$doc = new DOMDocument(); //fire up domdocument

$xmlstring = $xml->asXML(); //convert SimpleXML to string

$doc->loadXML($xmlstring);  //loads perfectly 

var_dump($doc); //empty object
```

Maybe you should consider [`SimpleXML`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php)?

Comment: As far as I know, until PHP 5.4, no internal classes expose properties with `var_dump`.  This does not necessarily mean they're empty, though.